# Having issue with AJAX's send method

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

I've created a sample (`index.html`) where when you click the button, the box's text content must be 'Hello World', which is in the `include.html` file. The problem is with the `send()` method, which says in the console

> POST http://localhost:8080/include.html 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>       document.querySelector.onclick @ main.js:10

here is the `main.js` file:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "include.html", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Can someone help me and give me some tips about this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Try to access the page using "GET" instead of "POST" in your `xhr.open(...)`

Comment: The web server (whichever one you're using) isn't allowing a POST request to `include.html`.  You'll have to check the server configuration.  A POST request to an HTML file doesn't seem to make sense anyway, since it has no way of meaningfully handling the request.

Comment: POST is locked down. GET may work or you may not have access at all. Basically this is a server side issue, not client side

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The 405 error means:`The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.`
try to use "GET" instead of "POST"

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made me avoid using the shortcut way of jQuery